# C# defining one method for different types of argument

Tags: c#

I've seen that you can define different functions for different sets of arguments in c#, like so:

```
public bool foo(string bar) {
    //do something1
}
public bool foo(int bar, bool spam) {
    //do something2
}
```

But can you make a single function definition for different sets of arguments? In my case, it'll be for `IList` and `List`. Since those types are only slightly varied I can use the same function for both `IList` and `List` objects (it's a simple function that just looks for some specific element). Is there any clever way of doing this, as in not a copypasta?

Thanks!

Comment: If one is derived from the other, or implements the interface (List implements IList), you can use the base type for both (IList, in this case).

Comment: You should search a bit about interfaces, they exist in Java too so that can't hurt.

Comment: Using the interface is the right way to do this, but have a read about generics too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, you could use only `IList` as the type of your parameter, since `List` implements `IList`.

For instance, you could declare

```
public void MethodName(IList list)
{
    // Method's body.
}
```

and the list you will pass could be either a concrete `List`  or a type that implements `IList`, without having to declare two mehods.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this, I'm quite new to C#

Comment: The advise given by Christos which i fully agree with also adheres to the design principle of "code against abstracts(interface) instead of concretes(types)", which is considered good practice.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that you can delcare `list` as `IEnumerable<T>` if you're just searching for an element in the collection.

Comment: @Lee I agree with you 100%, but I provided an answer in the given context. Certainly, it could be used the IEnumerable, since both List and IList implement it and it would be more general.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are trying to use `IList` and `List`. I don't think you need different methods for that. Because `List` implements `IList` and thus you can easily cast them in your code. So the same functions will work for both.

And if you are not modifying the items in the function then you can go little further and use `IEnumerable` as the parameter type.

such as -

```
protected void Method(IList list){

}
```

or

```
protected void Method(IEnumerable items){
}
```

But remember, there is a difference when using interfaces, they are passed by references and thus no new copy is created. Any modification you make will affect the original item collection. If you need to pass by value or want to create a new copy call `.ToList()` inside -

such as -

```
protected void Method(IList list){
    //some code
    var copied = list.ToList();
}
```

or

```
protected void Method(IEnumerable items){
    //some code
    var copied = items.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List object internally inherited by IList.
So use when you call method then convert IList to List object or List object to IList what ever you use   object type in method.